# return two values regex python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame where the values I want are in the same cell like this - words and all:

depth: 3230 m - 3750 m

I'm trying to write a regex to return the first number and then the second into a new data frame.
so far, I can get the values with this:

```
 top_depthdf=df[0].str.extract(r'depth:\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', flags=re.I).astype(float)
 base_depthdf=df[0].str.extract(r'-\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', flags=re.I).astype(float)
```

where I am having an issue is that these patterns are not unique in this data, especially the base depth one. Other numbers have a similar pattern and my script is returning them instead of the base depth if they occur before the depth row. I was wondering if there is a way to write the base_depthdf in such a way that it looks for the 'depth:' part first and then looks for that pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture these numbers with two *named capturing groups* into two columns at once:

```py
df_depth = df[0].str.extract(r'depth:\s*(?P<top_depth>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*\w+)?\s*-\s*(?P<base_depth>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nloko0/1). The `(?P<top_depth>...)` and `(?P<base_depth>...)` capture the details into separate columns.

I used `(?:\s*\w+)?\s*` to match a single optional word between the two patterns, but you may just use `.*?` if you are not sure what can appear between the two:

```py
df_depth = df[0].str.extract(r'depth:\s*(?P<top_depth>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?-\s*(?P<base_depth>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

Pandas test:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':['depth: 3230 m - 3750 m']})
df_depth = df['c'].str.extract(r'depth:\s*(?P<top_depth>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*\w+)?\s*-\s*(?P<base_depth>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
print(df_depth.to_string())
```

Output:

```
  top_depth base_depth
0      3230       3750
```

Comment: @Call_Me_Kevin You seem to be new to the site. The "thank you" comments are off-topic and are flagged and removed subsequently. Please consider reading [this MetaStackOverflow thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/251298#251298).